# Executed PHP files are stale unitl "touched" (Symlinked NFS mount as web root)

Tags: apache-2.2, php, nfs, deployment, alternative-php-cache

We have a PHP application that has 3 web servers (running Nginx and Apache). The web server's directory root are symlinked directories that point to an NFS mount. For example:

web01 has an NFS mount at `/data/webapp`, which is symlinked to `/home/webapp`. Apache serves content from `/home/webapp/www`.

We also use `ACP` for our PHP opcode cache. When we deploy code, we SCP an archive file to the NFS server and extract it.

Since upgrading RedHat 6, when we deploy our code the webserver execute "stale" PHP files until `touch` is run on the PHP files. We thought that `APC` might be causing a problem, but the issue exists, even after clearing the opcode cache.

Any ideas on how to diagnose why the stale PHP code is being executed?

Comment: Do you have any similar problems with non-PHP files? Have you tried disabling APC all together to check? (I mean, besides clearing the cache).

Comment: @ElBarto I disabled APC and have the same problem. Static files with Nginx seem to be served correctly...

Comment: PHP scripts are executed by Nginx or Apache? If it's Apache, can you check what happens if you serve a non-PHP file with Apache?

Comment: @ElBarto I did a few tests, Apache is serving stale files.

Answer (score 0):

That looks rather like editing-files-in-place issue. If you would be hitting this with nginx I'd recommend looking into your config for the [open_file_cache](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#open_file_cache) parameter, but almost the same thing happens inside of apache2 or php. The server caches file handles and totally misses a point when file changes failing to invalidate cache.

If apache is involed you can fix this once by issuing htcacheclean command and verifying that content was updated. If this is the case you need too peruse manual on [disk caching](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/caching.html). If not you should continue stripping php modules.

Comment: is htcacheclen only applicable when using mod_cache? We're not using that module...

Comment: This is rather about mod_file_cache. If it's not enabled I think you should proceed with php. I assume you can reproduce this issue on non-NFS mount so NFS caching can be left behind.